# Integration with Variable Equations Question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So some apologies for my previous posts. Haven't shared any context and I think some is deserved, I've been studying for the Calculus AP Test and have been using material I've been finding on my own along with some given by my math teacher. Just ran into the following question and I'm having a bit of trouble starting it. 
[image]

I worked through the part of transformations and I know that when applied to a function $f(x)$, $f(x) + 3$ shifts the graph up $3$, but I'm confused on how that would be applied to the equation here, I originally thought it would be as simple as just adding $3$ to the $2b$ term, but none of the answers seem to line up with my idea.

Comment: Hint: Recall that the integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

The curve of the function $ F : x\mapsto f(x)+3$ is obtained by an up translation of vector $ (3,0) $ of the curve of $ f$.

The integral of this function $ F $ at $ [a,b] $ represented by the area between the curve and the $ \vec{Ox} $ axis, is equal to the integrale of $ f $ plus the area of the rectangle [(a,0);(a,3);(b,3);(b,0)] , equal to $ 3(b-a)$.

Comment: Thanks! Clear and concise explanation and exactly what I needed.